# MVC 4 return View(model) statement returns page markup in form of text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, view

```
List<DepozytPositionModel> pozycje = Session["pozycje"] as List<DepozytPositionModel>;

                if (pozycje == null || !pozycje.Any())
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "blah blah");
                }

                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    TempData["guid"] = model.guid;
                    return View(model);
                }
```

As title says. When validation fails page should be reloaded with same data and validation information, right? Page is returned but content looks like this:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
      Returned view markup/code in form of raw text.
    </pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

The code at the beginning didn't change since we've used MVC3 and back then it worked perfectly fine. Any ideas?

Comment: "Returned view markup" - so you don't have the input fields that you expect, is that the issue?

Comment: @von v., I don't have layout, I don't have fields, I got view markup/code in form of raw text.

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of your layout and your view? Also, the same view you used on your post is the same view you used when you did `GET` and it's working fine for `GET` right?

Comment: Yes, it's the same view. I found out that the problem is caused by bad content-type, so I guess I'll just need to set it manually. Thanks a lot for your time;)

Answer (score 0):

Was caused by wrong content type (application/json instead of text/html).